# Is there a way to use Selenium WebDriver without informing the document that it is controlled by WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-w3c-spec

I'm automating an Web page who call a CAPTCHA to validate the login, but I noticed that this page only request this CAPTCHA when I'm using my automatized test code, when I do it manually it don't request. 
I asked to developer team to disable it on the QA environment, but it's not possible by a security code.

I need to know if there is a way to don't say to browser that I'm using automated test on this page.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: you can store cookies and directly by pass your login pages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461014/keep-user-logged-in-save-cookies-using-web-driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to conceal that you are runing automated test.

### WebDriver Interface

When using the [*WebDriver interface*](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#interface) the **webdriver-active flag** is set to true as the user agent is under remote control. It is initially false.

*WebIDL*

```
Navigator includes NavigatorAutomationInformation;
```

Note that the `NavigatorAutomationInformation` interface should not be exposed on WorkerNavigator.

*WebIDL*

```
interface mixin NavigatorAutomationInformation {
    readonly attribute boolean webdriver;
};
```

*webdriver*

- Returns true if webdriver-active flag is set, false otherwise.

Example

- For web authors :

  ```
  navigator.webdriver

  Defines a standard way for co-operating user agents to inform the document that it is controlled by WebDriver, for example so that alternate code paths can be triggered during automation.
  ```

The above mentioned implementation is based on a couple of [*Security Considerations*](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#security-considerations) as follows:

- A user agent can rely on a command-line flag or a configuration option to test whether to enable WebDriver, or alternatively make the user agent initiate or confirm the connection through a privileged content document or control widget, in case the user agent does not directly implement the HTTP endpoints.
- It is strongly suggested that user agents require users to take explicit action to enable WebDriver, and that WebDriver remains disabled in publicly consumed versions of the user agent.
- It is also suggested that user agents make an effort to visually distinguish a user agent session that is under control of WebDriver from those used for normal browsing sessions. This can be done through a browser chrome element such as a **door hanger**, colorful decoration of the OS window, or some widget element that is prevalent in the window so that it easy to identify automation windows.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Distil detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)