# Link is not clickable using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I get an error when trying to open a link via Selenium in:

- FireFox V. 73. 0 (64-bit)
- Geckodriver driver version-v0.26. 0

Help me solve the problem

```
public By searchResultLinktLocator(int searchResult) {
    By searchResultLinktLocator = By.xpath("//li[@data-result-number='" + searchResult + "']" + "//a");
    return searchResultLinktLocator;
}

public BBCSearchPage openSearchResultLink(int searchResult) {
    actions.click(driver.findElement(searchResultLinktLocator(searchResult))).perform();
    return this; 
}
```

The link for this function does not open:

```
searchPage.openSearchResultLink(1);
```

A page that does not open a link: https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=Andersen

```
1581606071797   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\anduser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileZpIGZz"
1581606072297   addons.webextension.doh-rollout@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'doh-rollout@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: networkStatus
1581606072791   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1581606072791   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1581606072791   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1581606072791   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1581606075330   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53959
1581606075570   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
фев 13, 2020 6:01:15 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript error: https://nav.files.bbci.co.uk/orbit/1b2e292884201dd13064a9204e177864/js/require.min.js, line 1: TypeError: e.slice is not a function
1581606081548   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
action.dispatch@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1034:5
performActions@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:850:16
dispatch/</req<@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:527:14
dispatch/<@chrome://marionette/content/listener.js:520:15
1581606081697   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081712   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081730   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081732   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081734   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081747   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081752   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081753   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081755   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081755   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081863   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081874   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081882   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081886   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081888   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081899   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081931   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
1581606081945   Marionette  WARN    TimedPromise timed out after 0 ms: stacktrace:
TimedPromise/<@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:244:13
TimedPromise@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:229:10
Sleep@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:282:10
dispatchPause@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1482:10
toEvents/<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1156:16
action.dispatchTickActions@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1060:35
action.dispatch/chainEvents<@chrome://marionette/content/action.js:1028:20
JavaScript error: , line 0: uncaught exception: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and simplified the structure and ran the test with minimal lines of code as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public class A_Firefox_Test 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/search?q=Andersen");
          int searchResult = 1;
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@data-result-number='" + searchResult + "']"))).click();
      }
  }
  ```

Similar to your observation I have hit the same roadblock, that the desired link wasn't clickable and additionally an *WARNING* as:

```
[Parent 7472, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: file z:/task_1579290903/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/base/process_util_win.cc, line 160
```

which implies the service was interupted within `process_util_win.cc` i.e. *process* module.

---

### Deep dive

I went ahead and while inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* it was observed that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **dist**. As an example:

- `map['idcta-v2/idcta-1'] = 'https://static.files.bbci.co.uk/account/id-cta/1.36.1/modules/idcta-v2/dist/idcta-1.min';`
- `document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.bbc.co.uk/bbcdotcom/3.6.969/script/dist/bbcdotcom.dev.js">\x3C/script>');`
- `document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.bbc.co.uk/bbcdotcom/3.6.969/script/dist/bbcdotcom.js">\x3C/script>');`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with Selenium was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Chrome browser initiated through ChromeDriver gets detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862023/is-there-a-way-to-use-selenium-webdriver-without-informing-the-document-that-it/52900495#52900495)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)
- [Is there a version of selenium webdriver that is not detectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-that-is-not-detectable-can-selenium-be-truly-un/56529616#56529616)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing `.build()` before the `.perform()`.

```
actions.click(driver.findElement(searchResultLinktLocator(searchResult))).build().perform()
```

Is this only failing on some searches, but working on others? You also didn't include where you're instantiating `actions`, that may help shed some light on the problem. If you update your post, I will update my answer.