# Data/Contents are missing when using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I am testing how to use Selenium in python, and successfully open a page via this below code in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options 
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/firefox'  
driver= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/home/myname/geckodriver',firefox_options=firefox_options)
driver.get('https://www.toutiao.com')
```

However, some data/contents are missing, comparing to open this page('https://www.toutiao.com') manually.

[image]

My Firefox version is '72.0.2' and geckodriver version is'0.26.0'. Could anybody help me on this issue please? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: question is not clear? do you want to verify this Text?

Comment: yes, there are texts here when I browser this page with Firefox but nothing here when I use selenium to open it

Comment: wait for page load maybe it takes time for page load

Comment: Are you giving proper time to  load page ? I have checked  page  and it take little long to load.

Comment: Yes, of course, I wait for a long time and the loading is already completed, but it is still blank using selenium. I can soon see the texts if I open the page in normal way.

Comment: Ohh It seems Compatibility issue. Which selenium version and browser version you are using?

Comment: it gives me the same issue in chrome driver too.

Comment: Same issue for me (Chrome version 79, Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: My version is  Firefox 'browserVersion': '72.0.2', 'geckodriverVersion': '0.26.0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code, simplified the script and while execution I have encountered the similar issue i.e. *the data/contents are missing comparing to open this page* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
      from selenium import webdriver

      driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
      driver.get('https://www.toutiao.com')
      print(driver.page_source)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
      <html><head><style class="vjs-styles-defaults">
            .video-js {
          width: 300px;
          height: 150px;
            }

            .vjs-fluid {
          padding-top: 56.25%
            }
          </style><meta charset="utf-8"><title>????</title><meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on"><meta name="renderer" content="webkit"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s3.pstatp.com/"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s3a.pstatp.com/"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//s3b.pstatp.com"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//p1.pstatp.com/"><link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//p3.pstatp.com/"><meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui"><meta name="360-site-verification" content="b96e1758dfc9156a410a4fb9520c5956"><meta name="360_ssp_verify" content="2ae4ad39552c45425bddb738efda3dbb"><meta name="google-site-verification" content="3PYTTW0s7IAfkReV8wAECfjIdKY-bQeSkVTyJNZpBKE"><meta name="shenma-site-verification" content="34c05607e2a9430ad4249ed48faaf7cb_1432711730"><meta name="baidu_union_verify" content="b88dd3920f970845bad8ad9f90d687f7"><meta name="domain_verify" content="pmrgi33nmfuw4ir2ej2g65lunfqw6ltdn5wselbcm52wszbchirdqyztge3tenrsgq3dknjume2tayrvmqytemlfmiydimddgu4gcnzcfqrhi2lnmvjwc5tfei5dcnbwhazdcobuhe2dqobrpu"><meta name="keywords" content="????,??,???,????,??????"><meta name="description" content="«????»(www.toutiao.com)????????????????,?????????????????,?????????????,??????????????????????"><link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="//m.toutiao.com/"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//s3a.pstatp.com/toutiao/resource/ntoutiao_web/static/image/favicon_5995b44.ico" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="stylesheet" href="//s3.pstatp.com/toutiao/player/dist/pc_vue2.css" media="screen" title="no title"><!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <p>?????????,?<a href="http://browsehappy.com/">?????</a></p>
      .
      .
      .
      <script>var imgUrl = '/c/9ubkblw9out4h9t6ya05r7h0uu7q2u341jhsdh7l4r4yphpuxlqgdm/';</script><script>tac='i+2gv2ch1tigds!i$1dmgs"yZl!%s"l"u&kLs#l l#vr*charCodeAtx0[!cb^i$1em7b*0d#>>>s j\uffeel  s#0,<8~z|\x7f@QGNCJF[\\^D\\KFYSk~^WSZhg,(lfi~ah`{md"inb|1d<,%Dscafgd"in,8[xtm}nLzNEGQMKAdGG^NTY\x1ckgd"inb<b|1d<g,&TboLr{m,(\x02)!jx-2n&vr$testxg,%@tug{mn ,%vrfkbm[!cb|'</script><script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//s3b.pstatp.com/toutiao/static/js/vendor.63b66d4280309ac2fb48.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//s3a.pstatp.com/toutiao/static/js/page/index_node/index.e6afc60a3a3f653cfdba.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" crossorigin="anonymous" src="//s3b.pstatp.com/toutiao/static/js/ttstatistics.a083f6cd9b1a9a970725.js"></script><script src="//s3.pstatp.com/inapp/lib/raven.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>;(function(window) {
          // sentry
          window.Raven && Raven.config('//key@m.toutiao.com/log/sentry/v2/96', {
            whitelistUrls: [/pstatp\.com/],
            shouldSendCallback: function(data) {
          var ua = navigator && navigator.userAgent;
          var isDeviceOK = !/Mobile|Linux/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
          return isDeviceOK;
            },
            tags: {
          bid: 'toutiao_pc',
          pid: 'index_new'
            },
            autoBreadcrumbs: {
          'xhr': false,
          'console': true,
          'dom': true,
          'location': true
            }
          }).install();
        })(window);</script><script>document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          var target = e.target,
          ga_event,
          ga_category,
          ga_label,
          ga_value;
          while(target && target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'BODY') {
            ga_event = target.getAttribute('ga_event');
            ga_category = target.getAttribute('ga_category') || '/';
            ga_label = target.getAttribute('ga_label') || '';
            ga_value = target.getAttribute('ga_value') || 1;

            ga_event && window.ttAnalysis && ttAnalysis.send('event', { ev: ga_event });
            target = target.parentNode;
          }
        });</script><script src="https://xxbg.snssdk.com/websdk/v1/getInfo?q=YOsueEs6CjZquUQrQwttBa2p27c%2FmJBGcEmZKypwf%2Fh%2B%2FFzCVrIwzk9L3bo%2FZb2O8gVTNaA4L2Bk10qWfZ2s94e6qe8KRXlOEjnI%2FrONB4jQynV3bfJ9exD2E4QPsgydRGjRLlDXE9uYD7HU3IZ%2FOU2MJG2vMgfNU55%2FmsOAlVSrPQH2wo4Eor0lgghKHjRi28vVvBdKY7JT4gG7S7ThRFD2YBIc%2Fs4JYViQu1Ll1Bg5Xn5bKuD6jZRz3AzfFqzSOWguO6vUbzL0wBc4mpa22mdpmAXIvUNWtjg5MUfXh9rfWI0ti7saL%2B0r4%2BaBdN5y4lrmxAcQZq2oeAKl4WjOeJsN%2BePpYmisoxTzdBZ6TL8IGE0E7ZUUlFlPGyUWhU3E4IRbtbCCd0QdVaJajiSOIhg9cImqTZYI56kIao1yVnV%2Bxu4%2BhaC1kHu5xsk49%2BX%2FNdwGcel%2BlOUzagkE5s8X6jEswA7jzW%2ByD6%2FusfkNyyx8WOWCJmZlTGQ4SNQr%2FQHvmK2QscQ7KnTvKVqjedUd7IFcvyTyYz3iFFrmRkOMRN9042sLiQwerXsn0f%2Fc%2Bh46PNdeU1S6BsFKq%2BZhMDxw1vI2Y1C%2Fa0RBdZC%2BGZq%2BkbNaoVotfvslg05ahevHTainlZR9DHEiWawFBJbTwjMeYrmo4NZiL5eNBUvslFn%2BDPHk%2F6Oj0Nbb89Rx8Ihi2pRH04voRog9848H2o2LR9gx0N0i0o6%3D&amp;callback=_8712_1581940674310"></script></body></html>
  ```

---

### Analysis

While inspecting the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) of the *webpage* you will find that some of the `<script>` tag refers to *JavaScripts* having keyword **dist**. As an example:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//s3.pstatp.com/toutiao/player/dist/pc_vue2.css" media="screen" title="no title">`
- `<script src="//unpkg.pstatp.com/byted/sec_sdk_build/1.1.12/dist/captcha.js"></script>`
- `//s3a.pstatp.com/toutiao/picc_mig/dist/img.min.js`

Which is a clear indication that the website is protected by **Bot Management** service provider [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/) and the navigation by *ChromeDriver* gets detected and subsequently **blocked**.

---

### Distil

As per the article [There Really Is Something About Distil.it...](https://www.forbes.com/sites/timconneally/2013/01/28/theres-something-about-distil-it/#6e1881e438b9):

> Distil protects sites against automatic content scraping bots by observing site behavior and identifying patterns peculiar to scrapers. When Distil identifies a malicious bot on one site, it creates a blacklisted behavioral profile that is deployed to all its customers. Something like a bot firewall, Distil detects patterns and reacts.

Further,

> `"One pattern with **Selenium** was automating the theft of Web content"`, Distil CEO Rami Essaid said in an interview last week. `"Even though they can create new bots, we figured out a way to identify Selenium the a tool they're using, so we're blocking Selenium no matter how many times they iterate on that bot. We're doing that now with Python and a lot of different technologies. Once we see a pattern emerge from one type of bot, then we work to reverse engineer the technology they use and identify it as malicious".`

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [Is there a way to use Selenium WebDriver without informing the document that it is controlled by WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862023/is-there-a-way-to-use-selenium-webdriver-without-informing-the-document-that-it/52900495#52900495)
- [Selenium webdriver: Modifying navigator.webdriver flag to prevent selenium detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039551/selenium-webdriver-modifying-navigator-webdriver-flag-to-prevent-selenium-detec/53040904#53040904)
- [Akamai Bot Manager detects WebDriver driven Chrome Browsing Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872920/clicking-on-get-data-button-for-monthly-settlement-statistics-on-nseindia-com-do/59874462#59874462)
- [Is there a version of selenium webdriver that is not detectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-that-is-not-detectable-can-selenium-be-truly-un/56529616#56529616)

Comment: Done! it seems there is no easy way to work this around though :(

Comment: @X.C. There are a couple of ways to try out to work this around, but that would be beyond the scope of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491). See the reference discussions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323836/access-denied-page-with-headless-chrome-on-linux-while-headed-chrome-works-on-wi/59331061#59331061) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123142/selenium-and-non-headless-browser-keeps-asking-for-captcha/56136820#56136820) discussion.

Comment: using headless mode is probably even harder..I tried set up a user agent, but still no avail.